# Unable to refresh token after expiration

Tags: ruby, oauth, soundcloud

I can authenticate and fetch an access_token and the corresponding refresh_token fine (subsequent API interactions are also fine).

However, I seem to only be able to refresh a token (`POST` to `/oauth/token` with `grant_type=refresh_token`) *before* the `access_token` actually expires. After the expiration, the same refresh code (exactly that provided within the docs), returns with an error of `invalid_grant`.

I am using the soundcloud-ruby SDK, FWIW, but I can reproduce it through curl.

As an aside, I found some old messages from the Google Group mentioning that I can request a non-expiring token, but I do not see this mentioned anywhere in the docs. Is this still a viable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. Refresh tokens cannot be used after an access token expires.

You can request a non-expiring access token by specifying `scope=non-expiring` when constructing an authorization URL. To do this with the Ruby SDK, simply pass the additional params to the `authorize_url` method:

```
require 'soundcloud'

client = Soundcloud.new(
  :client_id => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  :client_secret => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  :redirect_uri => 'REDIRECT_URI'
)

client.authorize_url(:scope => 'non-expiring')
```

The rest of the flow should be exactly the same (grab the 'code' parameter from the query string and make a `POST` request to `/oauth2/token`).

Comment: If a refresh-token cannot be used to request an access-token after it has expired, then what is it's purpose within the SDK? From what I gather in the Oauth RFC, the refresh-token's expressed intent is to allow for access-tokens to gained again without the user having to re-authorize.

Comment: That's not correct: with google Oauth2 you can refresh tokens if expired

Comment: Does this non expiring token won't need refreshing ever ?

Comment: @RohitKhatri : it seems that it expire if the user change his password

Comment: @Julien Thanks :-)