# Google OAuth2 Refresh_token expires when Access_token does

Tags: google-oauth

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev discussion is now here.

No matter how much reading I do, I can't get my head around how google OAuth2 tokens work. Reading the docs and many other places suggest that a refresh_token doesn't expire, and is used once the access_token expires. See the official docs at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

However, in practice it appears to work as describe by Paul ([Unable to refresh token after expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976912/unable-to-refresh-token-after-expiration)) that the refresh token expires when the access token expires.

Can a Google Engineer please confirm what the correct behavior should be as this appears to be a case of behavior and documentation not matching.

It also makes the refresh token useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you request `access_type=offline` when making the initial request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` then you'll get back a refresh token along with the access token. [This is documented here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).

The refresh token *does not expire*, until the user explicitly revokes access to it from the [Account -> Security -> "Connected applications and sites"](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens) page.

The other post you linked to seems to be related to SoundCloud, which presumably does things a little differently.

Comment: Thanks Dean. After some investigation by using the Google Oauth2 Playground, I can confirm that refresh_tokens are both valid after the access token expires, and can be used regardless of the state of the access token. (Some had suggested it wouldn't work until the access_token expired).
My difficulty appears to have been escaping of the refresh_token by the library I was using, and then further escaping by the library on displaying the token. Using OAuth2 playground I realised my tokens didn't look right as they had the extra escape chars

Comment: I cant get a refresh token even with access_type=offline :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678496/google-oauth-access-token-expiration-in-mvc-app

Comment: is their a way we can check if my refresh access token is revoked or not before using it..?