# Retrieving refresh and access token from google api while gmail login

Tags: android, google-api, access-token

I am trying to allow user login through gmail with the help of google api. I am able to login and also retrieve the personal information but not able to retrieve refresh and access tokens which are generated on successful login of the user. How could I retrieve that since I need to send that details to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to my post with the answer, it's in MVC app, but the concept is the same.
You get refresh token only once, when you get that consent screen, you need to record it somewhere and re-assign to the access token. Just scroll to the Answer, I explained it there. Hope this helps.

[Google OAuth access token expiration in MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678496/google-oauth-access-token-expiration-in-mvc-app)

Comment: I want to retrieve the token in Android and not in ASP.net. I am trying the method defined in the api but getting an excepton.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I don't know Android, just presented the concept, not a solution for you code, for general understanding. Not sure what is going on in Android API, sorry :)