# Google Fit Api 403 Error from remote client

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-7, google-api, google-fit

I have a web app hosted on IIS 7 that is doing Http calls using the Google Fit API, I'm able to successfully send a POST and retrieve an access token, after which I do a GET for the following uri:

"https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/raw:com.google.weight:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input/datasets/00-1427209862000000000"

Here's how I build a request and look at the response:

```
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + dict["access_token"]);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        sResponse = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
        respStream.Close();
        Response.Write(sResponse);
```

When I run this app on a browser on the host server, I successfully get a json object (it isn't the json I expect, but that's another issue). However, when I try to access the site on a remote client, I get a 403 error pointing to when I try to retrieve the response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This turned out to be a permissions issue. I was trying to access a data source that I didn't have scopes for, the fact that it didn't return a 403 when accessing on the host threw me off the trail. Still strange that it didn't return a 403 (it just returned an empty json object) when requested on the host server though...if you see this and have an idea why, feel free to comment. I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends how you got the `access_token` value.

How long after retrieving the access token are you making this request?  It's only valid for an hour, so you may need to fetch a new one using the refresh token.

There's some more resources on access/refresh tokens this question:

[Google OAuth2 Refresh_token expires when Access_token does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576964/google-oauth2-refresh-token-expires-when-access-token-does)

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to update this. It actually was a permissions issue that I overlooked. Thank you for your response though!